# Variable Explorer freezes when viewing tuples in python Spyder IDE

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples, anaconda, spyder

I am having a problem with the Variable Explorer in Anaconda 1.9.2 (64-bit) Spyder 2.2.5, Python 2.7

It is a new problem; I don't know what has changed recently.

I run my script in debug mode, and continue to the first break point.  My Variable explorer window has a mix of variables: str, int, float, tuples.  When I double-click on the Value of any tuple, Spyder opens a new popo-up window for the variable, but it immediately freezes and the title is " Tuple (Not Responding)".  Waiting does not solve the problem, and I have to kill the process, which makes the interpreter window go inactive, and I have to start over.

Other data types work fine in the Variable explorer, and it does not seem related to the size of the tuple.  I created a local variable %dog = ('breed','retriever') and tried to view it...also locks up the process.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

By definition a tuple is an immutable list.
That error is related with that feature of the tuple.
That is the reason because the error raise only with the type tuple.

You can use a list instead a tuple.
Try this:

```
>>>a=(1,2,3)
>>>b=list(a)
>>>b
>>>[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I'm not trying to change the values in the tuple, I just want to view it.  It is truncated in the Variable Explorer with '...' since it can't all fit on two lines.  I want to display the contents in row/column format in the separate window, not wrapping like it does in the interpreter window.  The freeze error is now happening with "list" data types.

Comment: I'm going to try here with my spyder

Comment: Sorry I can't reproduce that error. May be the problem is in the element of this tuple. Are you able to print the tuple?

Comment: Here is the debug code I'm running:                                                             # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Jul 21 16:24:03 2015

@author: tyler.davis
"""

dogtuple = ('breed','poodle')
doglist = list(dogtuple)                                                                                  I can print dogtuple and doglist to the (Pdb) screen, but if I try to view either in the Variable Explorer editor, it freezes as "Not Responding"